# jquery get part from div and generate a link

Tags: html, jquery, loops

I've somewhat like that several times with different values. I want to grab only the Username from the div "user-info". Furthermore, I want to make this div-container as a link which contains the Username.
This is my code I've to handle:

```
<div class="user-info">


Username a

<div class="female"></div>


(19)

</div>


<div class="user-info">
    
    
Username b
    
<div class="male"></div>
    
    
(26)
    
</div>
```

This is what I already have:

```
var nick = $.trim($(".user-info")
.text()
.split("\n")[3]);
$ (".user-info")
  .contents()
  .filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType !== 1;
  })
.wrap('<a href=https://this.website.com/link&nickname='+nick+'></a>');
```

This just works for the first div-container. I think, I need a more specific loop. But I can't find, how to do that.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) from jquery, where `this` is your `user-info` element in the loop.

```
$(".user-info").each(function() {
  var nick = $.trim($(this))
  .text()
  .split("\n")[3]);
  $(this)
    contents()
    .filter(function(){
      return this.nodeType !== 1;
    })
  .wrap('<a href=https://this.website.com/link&nickname='+nick+'></a>');
});
```